# Implementation of ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> prevents registration of @Scheduled & @Async methods

Tags: spring

I have a Service class in which I wish to invoke a method after the application context has been initialized and ALL the beans & annotations have been initialized and registered respectively:

```
    @Service
    public class EventGenerator implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{

        static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EventGenerator.class);

        @Autowired
        private JsonQueryService service;

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

           generateFlights();

        }

        @Async
        private void generateFlights(){

            while(true){

                 try{  

                    List<FlightJson> jsons = service.parseJSONFeed();

                    checkHexcodeAndMappings(jsons);

                    updateSquark(jsons);

                        Thread.sleep(10000);   

                      }catch(InterruptedException e){  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                      }  

                    }       
            }

  }
```

I also have other @Scheduled and @Async annotations in the application. What I don't understand is why when I call the *generateFlights()* method, ALL the @Scheduled and @Async annotations in the application are **not** registered.

If I **do not** call the *generatFlights()* method within the *onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)* method, then the annotated methods are registered normally and the respective cron tasks / asynchronous methods run normally.

Here is the root application context body (without namespace declarations):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.atlaschase.product.core">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex"
            expression="com.atlaschase.product.core.bootstrap.populators.*" />
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex"
            expression="com.atlaschase.product.core.services.jms.*" />
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex"
            expression="com.atlaschase.product.core.services.processor.*" />
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex"
            expression="com.atlaschase.product.core.services.remote.*" />           
    </context:component-scan>

    <import resource="classpath:core-properties.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:core-datasource.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:core-task-scheduler.xml" />
```

Here is the *core-task-scheduler.xml* application context which contains details of executor configuration (again, namespaces ommitted):

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="1"/>
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="5"/>
```

Any insight into why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by the infinite loop in the `generateFlights()` method.  This could be preventing the execution of the program from being handed back to Spring.

```
private void generateFlights(){
    while(true){ //Never going to stop
       try{  
          List<FlightJson> jsons = service.parseJSONFeed();
          checkHexcodeAndMappings(jsons);
          updateSquark(jsons);
          Thread.sleep(10000);   
       }catch(InterruptedException e){  
          e.printStackTrace();  
       }  
     }       
}
```

If you need this method to execute every second, try adding `@Scheduled` to the method.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
private void generateFlights(){
       try{  
          List<FlightJson> jsons = service.parseJSONFeed();
          checkHexcodeAndMappings(jsons);
          updateSquark(jsons);  
       }catch(Exception e){  
          e.printStackTrace();  
       }  
     }       
}
```

For this to work the class containing this method must be registered as a Spring Bean.

Comment: You approach has worked. Adding the @Scheduled annotation did the trick nicely. I through away the ApplicationListener entirely. Thank you!